# AVPlayer is running double songs iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer in my application and its running good in background but problem is that when i go back and select other song to play then first song not stopped and both songs running parallel.Here is my code that i am using to run songs in my app

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:0 error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
AVPlayerItem * item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.songURL]];
    _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[_player currentItem]];
    // Set AVAudioSession
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];

    // Change the default output audio route
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                            sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

    NSArray *queue = @[item];

    self.player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:queue];
    self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance;

    [self.player addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"currentItem"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:nil];
    void (^observerBlock)(CMTime time) = ^(CMTime time) {
        NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.2f", ((float)time.value / (float)time.timescale)/60];
        AVPlayerItem *currentItem = _player.currentItem;
        NSTimeInterval currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime);
        NSLog(@" Capturing Time :%f ",currentTime);
        //             NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentTime.timescale];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
            self.currentTrackTime.text = timeString;
            NSLog(@"%@ jjjj",timeString);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"App is backgrounded. Time is: %@", timeString);
        }
    };

    self.timeObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(10, 1000)
                                                                  queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                                             usingBlock:observerBlock];


}
[self.player play];
```

Kindly Help me out if any one know about this problem. Your help will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: if you are adding the observer dont forget to remove the observer.

Comment: How can i remove observer ? can you share with me any sample code?

Comment: Example for removing AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
               
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];